# Multiply 2D NumPy arrays element-wise and sum

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I am wondering if there is a quicker way/dedicated NumPy function to perform element-wise multiplication of 2D NumPy arrays and then sum all the elements.
I currently use `np.sum(np.multiply(A, B))` where A, B are NumPy arrays of equal dimension `m x n`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(A,B, axes=((0,1),(0,1)))
```

Another way with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) after flattening the inputs -

```
A.ravel().dot(B.ravel())
```

Another with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ij',A,B)
```

Sample run -

```
In [14]: m,n = 4,5

In [15]: A = np.random.rand(m,n)

In [16]: B = np.random.rand(m,n)

In [17]: np.sum(np.multiply(A, B))
Out[17]: 5.1783176986341335

In [18]: np.tensordot(A,B, axes=((0,1),(0,1)))
Out[18]: array(5.1783176986341335)

In [22]: A.ravel().dot(B.ravel())
Out[22]: 5.1783176986341335

In [21]: np.einsum('ij,ij',A,B)
Out[21]: 5.1783176986341326
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [23]: m,n = 5000,5000

In [24]: A = np.random.rand(m,n)
    ...: B = np.random.rand(m,n)
    ...: 

In [25]: %timeit np.sum(np.multiply(A, B))
    ...: %timeit np.tensordot(A,B, axes=((0,1),(0,1)))
    ...: %timeit A.ravel().dot(B.ravel())
    ...: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij',A,B)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 52.2 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 19 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. On my application with 45x45 arrays, I found the ravel().dot() option to be significantly faster.