# Which is a quick way to parallelize element-wise multiplication of 2D NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing, mpi4py

I use a NumPy function [einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to perform element-wise multiplication of two 2D NumPy arrays and sum.

```
np.einsum('ij,ij',A,B)
```

Each of these array A, B are sized around `10000 x 10000`. I notice  this operation is the bottleneck in my code taking up ~85 % of the processing time. How do I quickly parallelize this operation?

Comment: Don't the other solutions to your previous question work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763949/3293881

Comment: The choice of function `einsum` to perform element-wise multiplication and sum does work. And it is the quickest of the rest for my system. However, as I mentioned in the post, the operation is still slow and acts as a bottleneck.

Comment: You could install [`tensorflow`](https://www.tensorflow.org/) with GPU acceleration and use their [`einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) function. It's very similar to `numpy`'s.

Comment: I do not have access to GPUs, and however, is there a way to accelerate this calculation by parallelizing over CPUs with tools available within Python like [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/index.html)?

Comment: @Viswanath Sure, just distribute the matrices over your nodes and use [`MPI_REDUCE`](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/) together with `MPI_SUM`. This operation trivially scales horizontally. But note that you are introducing some overhead due to network bandwith and latency.

Comment: A "bottleneck" mostly makes sense if there's an unreasonable slow-down in your code that should be fixed. In your case if most of the time is spent in einsum then _your task is CPU heavy_, period. @Divakar's timing on the linked answer suggests that a 5k*5k problem can run in less than 20 ms on whatever machine he's using. So either you're barking up the wrong tree, or I'm missing something obvious.