# Parallelize for-loop in Python over threads/cores/nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, parallel-processing, mpi4py

I intend to parallelize a for-loop in Python as shown below handling large data arrays. How does parallelization over threads/cores/nodes suit this code, and how to implement it? Any advise is appreciated. Thanks!

All the inputs are NumPy arrays with the following typical sizes:

```
vector_data (int64): 1M x 3
matrix (float64): 0.1M x 0.1M x 3
```

**Edits based on answers to the post:**

Test for run-time performance suggest `multiprocessing` results in a significant slowdown as well have higher memory requirements.

```py
from timeit import timeit
from multiprocessing import Pool

import numpy as np
from numba import jit

def OP():
    N = len(matrix_data)
    pop_array = np.zeros((N, N))
    for vector in vector_data:
        vector_2 = np.dot(vector, vector)
        pop_array += (np.exp(-vector_2) / vector_2
                      * np.cos(np.tensordot(matrix_data, vector, axes=([2], [0]))))
    return pop_array

def worker(vector):
    vector_2 = np.dot(vector, vector)
    return (np.exp(-vector_2) / vector_2
            * np.cos(np.tensordot(matrix_data, vector, axes=([2], [0]))))

def f1():
    N = len(matrix_data)
    pop_array = np.zeros((N, N))

    with Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, vector_data)

    for res in results:
        pop_array += res

    return pop_array

def f2():
    N = len(matrix_data)
    pop_array = np.zeros((N, N))

    with Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.imap(worker, vector_data):
            pop_array += result

    return pop_array

jit(parallel=True)
def f3():
    N = len(matrix_data)
    pop_array = np.zeros((N, N)) 
    for vector in vector_data:
        vector_2 = np.dot(vector, vector)
        pop_array += (np.exp(-vector_2) / vector_2
                      * np.cos(np.tensordot(matrix_data, vector, axes=([2], [0]))))
    return pop_array

max_vector_index = 150
vector_size = int(1E3)
matrix_size = int(1E2)

vector_shape = vector_size, 3
matrix_shape = matrix_size, matrix_size, 3

vector_data = np.random.randint(-max_vector_index, max_vector_index+1, vector_shape)
matrix_data = np.random.random(matrix_shape)

print(f'OP: {timeit(OP, number=10):.3e} sec')
print(f'f1: {timeit(f1, number=10):.3e} sec')
print(f'f2: {timeit(f2, number=10):.3e} sec')
print(f'f3: {timeit(f3, number=10):.3e} sec')
```

Following are the run-time costs from sample runs:

```
vector_size = int(1E2)
matrix_size = int(1E1)

OP: 9.527e-02 sec
f1: 2.402e+00 sec (25.21x)
f2: 2.269e+00 sec (23.82x)
f3: 3.414e-02 sec (0.36x)

OP: 43.0 MiB
f1: 41.9 MiB (0.97x)
f2: 41.9 MiB (0.97x)
```

```
vector_size = int(1E3)
matrix_size = int(1E2)

OP: 1.420e+00 sec
f1: 1.448e+01 sec (10.20x)
f2: 2.051e+01 sec (14.44x)
f3: 1.213e+00 sec (0.86x)

OP: 43.4 MiB
f1: 119.0 MiB (2.74x)
f2: 43.8 MiB (1x)
```

```
vector_size = int(1E4)
matrix_size = int(1E3)

OP: 5.116e+02 sec
f1: 8.902e+02 sec (1.74x)
f2: 6.509e+02 sec (1.27x)

OP: 73.9 MiB
f1: 76402.1 MiB (1033x)
f2: 209.7 MiB (2.84x)
```

Comment: `numba` [provides some support for parallelization](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html)

Comment: It seems that you are repeating and repeating the same sort of questions as in 2017 and earlier, without any efforts spent on efficient solving this whole sort of performance problems, but by asking again - or did we miss some research and testing a tuning to avoid the known for-loops' poor performance?
---
For details Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888667/which-is-a-quick-way-to-parallelize-element-wise-multiplication-of-2d-numpy-arra#comment76934400_44888667

Comment: The numpy functions do already run in parallel. How would you expect futher parallelization be more efficient? You would expect an additional overhead, right?

Comment: You can try [ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), it's for distributed computing but also works on a single machine

Answer (score 9):

You could use a [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). Then you can use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) method to run a function on an iterable. So you could first create the function to be passed to the workers to work on each element from the iterable:

```py
def worker(vector):
    vector_2 = np.dot(vector, vector)
    return (np.exp(-vector_2) / vector_2
            * np.cos(np.tensordot(matrix, vector, axes=([2], [0]))))
```

Now you can create the [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) to run this function on each vector. It will return a list of the results and then we can add those results to `pop_array`. Like so:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def par_fun(vector_data, matrix):
    N = len(matrixA)
    pop_array = np.zeros((N, N))

    with Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, vector_data)

    for res in results:
        pop_array += res

    return pop_array
```

---

Another possible neater way is to use [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap). From the docs:

> Note that it may cause high memory usage for very long iterables.
>   Consider using [imap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) or [imap_unordered()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) with explicit *chunksize*
>   option for better efficiency.

Also:

> The *chunksize* argument is the same as the one used by the [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)
>   method. For very long iterables using a large value for *chunksize* can
>   make the job complete **much** faster than using the default value of `1`.

So you can use this code:

```py
def par_fun(vector_data, matrix):
    N = len(matrixA)
    pop_array = np.zeros((N, N))

    pool_size = None
    chunksize = 1

    with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap(worker, vector_data, chunksize=chunksize):
            pop_array += result

    return pop_array
```

And play with different `pool_size` and `chunksize` values to acheive best results.

---

Another option, is to use Threads instead of Processes. Processes have an overhead of creation and maintenence that might affect run-time. To change the code to use threads, simply change the import to use the [`dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) wrapper:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

The rest of the code(s) stay the same

Comment: **Would you mind to kindly benchmark both the setup-costs** ( time [us], space [GB] ) **and** separately **the actual computing-part durations in [us]?** In other words, to post benchmarked hard-facts about how many [us] of time you "pay" for making the process "run" and compute a result over 1E3, 1E6, 1E9 [B]-sized data? Without this part of the story the promises are sort of unfair to give as an advice, are they? This is fair to tell the story complete, without these hidden (and sometimes brutal) costs, isn't it?

Comment: @user3666197 How do you test memory costs?

Comment: @Viswanath by profiling - that's an obvious tool / using an external monitoring of system-reported process-related allocations at worse.

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks. I've profiled the code for memory requirements and it turns out `multiprocessing` is not helpful. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Viswanath Okay, 've profiled the code ... **and the results are .....** ... [us] ... [GB] for pure-serial run and ... [us] ... [GB] for respective sizes of multiprocessing.Pool()-sizing runs? The quantitative results matter.

Comment: Yes, I edited the post including the quantitative data before adding the earlier comment. OP() is a pure-serial run, while f1(), f2() uses multiprocessing.Pool(). Please refer to the edited post for run-time and memory usage information.